# How to implement lazy evaluation of objective-C property which may be nil?

Tags: objective-c, thread-safety, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation, lazy-initialization

In objective-C, how can I properly implement lazy evaluation of a property which may be nil?

The usual practice is demonstrated below, however it does not work properly for properties which may be nil - Their initialization won't be performed just once.

```
@interface LZClass: NSObject
@property (strong, readonly) NSString * lazyProp;
@end

@implementation LZClass

@synthesize lazyProp = _lazyProp;
- (NSString *)lazyProp {
    if (_lazyProp == nil) {
        _lazyProp = <Some Calculation>;
    }
    return _lazyProp
}

@end
```

Comment: Use dispatch_once, or simply have a separate boolean variable.

Answer (score -3):

Update: This answer isn't safe. See Yan's comment below. Leaving it here so people who have the same idea can beware.

---

Use `dispatch_once` instead of checking for nil.

```
@interface LZClass: NSObject {
    dispatch_once_t _onceToken;
}
@property (strong, readonly) NSString * lazyProp;
@end

@implementation LZClass

@synthesize lazyProp = _lazyProp;
- (NSString *)lazyProp {
    dispatch_once(&_onceToken, ^{
        _lazyProp = <Some Calculation>;
    }
    return _lazyProp
}

@end
```

This also has the advantage of being thread-safe. Threads trying to read the property while the initialization block is already being executed will block, and continue after the initialization block returns. Therefore the correct result is guaranteed to be returned in all threads.

Also beware: the standard code snippet for `dispatch_once` defines a static `onceToken`, which won't work correctly here; the initialization block will only be executed for the first object of the class.

Comment: You can not use dispatch_once with instance variable for predicate: "The predicate must point to a variable stored in global or static scope. The result of using a predicate with automatic or dynamic storage (including Objective-C instance variables) is undefined." See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-DontLinkElementID_50